# Quadratic form, definite/semidefnite

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering what the difference between positive definite and semidefinite is.

By definition positive definite is $x^TAx$ > 0 for all x ≠ 0
and positive semidefinite is $x^TAx$ ≥ 0 for all x ≠ 0

This is the definition I got from my textbook. I can't tell what the difference is between the two definitions. It seems they are both saying the same thing. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$For example,
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&4\cr}$$
is positive semidefinite but not positive definite.  We have
$$\\x^TA\\x=x^2+4xy+4y^2=(x+2y)^2\ .$$

Positive definite: $(x+2y)^2>0$ for all $(x,y)\ne\\0$: FALSE, because the expression is also zero when $(x,y)=(2,-1)$.

Positive semidefinite: $(x+2y)^2\ge0$ for all $(x,y)$: TRUE.  (Note that in your definition of semidefinite, the stipulation that $\\x\ne\\0$ is redundant.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! makes sense to me now :)